# The number of digits on textField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm working on my app and I need help on `UITextField`.

I want to make the number of digits that appear to be specific (e.g. 3) knowing that the numbers shown on the `UITextField` is from the value of the slider between the range of 1 to 0 (I need this range,) with numbers between them (0.5 , 0.6 ...).

The numbers I am getting is 6 digits (0.123456) and I would like it to show less than that.

I have tried this funcion after added `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
...
}
```

But it's not working. I got help from some one to use this function:

```
@IBAction func testField(sender: UITextField) {
    let TheLength = sender.text!.characters.count
    if TheLength = >= 3 {
        let TheRange = Range(start: sender.text!.startIndex, end: sender.text!.startIndex.advancedBy(3))
        var newdi = sender.text!.substringWithRange(TheRange)
        sender.text = newdi
    }
}
```

Also nothing changed.

Note: I have more `UITextFields` to fix.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want your slider to go from 0 to 1, in increments of 0.1. So it goes 0.0, 0.1, 0.2 etc up to 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it something like this.

```
textField.text = String(format: "%0.1f", slider.value)
```